# Jest "Cannot find module" with typescript paths in CI

Tags: jestjs, tsconfig, ts-jest, nrwl-nx

On the Gitlab-CI environment 2 of our Jest tests fail with `Cannot find module`.
The strange thing is that it works on my local Win10 machine - even when I run the tests in a similar docker-container (`node 12.12.0`).

Here is the console output:

```
FAIL apps/server/src/domain/dashboard/permission-group.service.spec.ts
Test suite failed to run
  Cannot find module '@cm/utils-server' from 'license.service.ts'
     9 |   isLicenseFileContent,
    10 |   LicenseStatus,
  > 11 |   parseLicenseInfo
       |                   ^
    12 | } from '@cm/license-shared';
    13 | import { ExitCode } from '../../util/exit-codes';
    14 | import { readFile } from '@cm/utils-server';
    at Resolver.resolveModule (../../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (src/domain/license/license.service.ts:11:24)
```

I am not sure how to correctly interpret this output:

1. `permission-group.service.spec.ts`: this is the test that fails
2. `Cannot find module '@cm/utils-server' from 'license.service.ts'`:
   Ok, the test or some of its dependencies, use `license.service.ts` and in the `license.service.ts` file the `'@cm/utils-server'` module cannot be found.
3. What is the meaning of error-indicator (`>` at `parseLicenseInfo`)?

   - This is for the import `@cm/license-shared` - not for `@cm/utils-server` as indicated by the error message in 2
   - `@cm/utils-server` is also imported, but 2 lines below in line 14: So is this maybe just a bug in jest?

Comment: Having the same issue... if you found a resolution, I would love to hear it.

Comment: @Donovan currently only a workaround: we had `paths` defined in multiple `tsconfig.json` files of our mono-repo. We moved all paths up to the root-tsconfig and now the tests work again. But we don't really understand why this works. And this has the drawback that it is now easy to accicentially refer to a path that you shouldn't use in the lib (because the IDE now always uses all paths for code-assistance)

Answer (score 14):

I just had this issue and searched for some solutions. Found [this](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50171412.html) site which gave a clue about what could be done: to configure Jest's moduleNameMapper property.

So, reading the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) I found this solution:

1. Open the `tsconfig.json` and `jest.config.js` files (or equivalent)
2. In `tsconfig.json`, find your absolute paths definition. My configuration looks like this:

```
"paths": {
    "@modules/*": ["modules/*"],
    "@config/*": ["config/*"],
    "@shared/*": ["shared/*"]
}
```

3. In the `jest.config.json`, find and uncomment the `moduleNameMapper` property and start to translate your TS absolute paths into the Jest mapper syntax. Sounds complicated, but it isn't:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    "@modules/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/modules/$1",
    "@config/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/config/$1",
    "@shared/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/shared/$1",
}
```

- The `<rootDir>` if defined automatically, and points to the `package.json` directory
- `"@modules/(.*)"` is a Regex for "any string starting with '@module/' followed by anything after it
- `"<rootDir>/src/modules/$1"` is the corresponding directory. `$1` is a pointer to the Regex expression between the parenthesis (`(.*)`). Other expressions will be pointed by `$2`, `$3` and so on

After doing this, I was able to execute my tests without any problem.

Console output before follow the above steps:

```
$ jest
 FAIL  src/modules/appointments/services/CreateAppointmentService.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '...'
```

Console output after:

```
$ jest
 PASS  src/modules/appointments/services/CreateAppointmentService.spec.ts
```

Hope this help someone,
Thanks!

Comment: It can be simplified by pathsToModuleNameMapper() method in ts-jest/utils.
https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping/
In this case, the prefix should be set to <rootDir>/src

Answer (score 2):

For those who are facing this issue in 2022. Please add this code in your
`jest-unit.json (or your jest config json file)`.

```
"moduleDirectories": ["<rootDir>/../", "node_modules"]
```

Result:

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".\\.spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "moduleDirectories": ["<rootDir>/../", "node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now we use a workaround: we had paths defined in multiple tsconfig.json files of our mono-repo. We moved all paths up to the root-tsconfig and now the tests work again.
But we don't really understand why this works.

And a drawback is that it's now easy to accidentally refer to a path that you shouldn't use in the lib (because the IDE now always uses all paths for code-assistance)

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, I found the reason is the package(which cannot found) doesn't set the main field in package.json, add it then everythings ok.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).