# "Cannot find module" (How to use Jest in a nested project that uses a shared folder)

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I've inherited a project that has folders like:

```
node_modules/
server/
├── node_modules/
├── src/
│   └── helpers/
│       ├── updateTransactions.ts
│       └── updateTransactions.test.ts
├── jest.config.ts
└── tsconfig.json
shared/
└── helpers/
    └── datetime.ts
src/
└── index.tsx
jest.config.ts
tsconfig.json
```

If I `cd` into `server` and run `yarn test`, I get `Cannot find module '../../../shared/helpers/datetime.js' from 'src/helpers/updateTransactions.ts'`

I think it's just because Jest does not yet have awareness of how to interpret `import { getFormattedDatetimeUtcFromBlockTimestamp } from '../../../shared/helpers/datetime.js';` in updateTransactions.ts.

It's probably a simple configuration issue.

As you can see in various commented-out code [here](https://github.com/NEARFoundation/tx-tracking-app/blob/f8f104027d3da32dc84b8794526693968ef0ad23/server/jest.config.ts), I've tried all sorts of things:

- [Jest + Typescript + Absolute paths (baseUrl) gives error: Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171412/jest-typescript-absolute-paths-baseurl-gives-error-cannot-find-module)
- [Jest gives `Cannot find module` when importing components with absolute paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863312/jest-gives-cannot-find-module-when-importing-components-with-absolute-paths)
- [Jest "Cannot find module" with typescript paths in CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116570/jest-cannot-find-module-with-typescript-paths-in-ci)
- [Problem mapping path in ts-jest (TypeScript Jest), module cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71651655/problem-mapping-path-in-ts-jest-typescript-jest-module-cannot-be-found)

Comment: Looks like you resolved the issue on your own?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main [change](https://github.com/NEARFoundation/tx-tracking-app/commit/c646337808cbbdde6e62b1507243da78011f5043) that helped it work was to make my `jest.config.ts`:

```
// https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/

/* eslint-disable canonical/filename-match-exported */
import { type JestConfigWithTsJest } from 'ts-jest';

const jestConfig: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  // [...]
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm', // or other ESM presets
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
  },
  transform: {
    // '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts with `ts-jest`
    // '^.+\\.m?[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts/mjs/mts with `ts-jest`
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default jestConfig;
```

See docs: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/